# É possível criar jogos 3d com pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

É possível? E se for possível eu preciso saber desenhar minhas próprias imagens 3d ou existe algum site que disponibilize imagens 3d gratis?

Comment: Pygame vem como uma camada de abstração entre Python e SDL. Se não me engano SDL é focada em 2D. Não me lembro se há suporte para 3D, ou se você deveria fazer na mão. Mas se você quiser apenas uma alternativa tipo DonkeyKong, aquilo foi um conjunto de impressões de um modelo 3D em um sprite 2D dando sensação de profundidade

Comment: Olá, bem vindo ao SOPT. Tenho sérias dúvidas a respeito dessa pergunta estar bem formatada para este site. Sugiro fazer o [tour] e ler [ask]. Enquanto isso, na sala de justiça... sim, é possível. Mas como já comentaram, o Pygame não vai te ajudar diretamente com o 3D. Vc precisará de outras coisas, como o [PyOpenGL](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/). Há também outras alternativas (leia mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4304018/2896619)).

Comment: Sobre obter modelos e texturas 3D, o ideal é que vc mesmo faça (ou contrate alguém que faça). Mas vc pode comprar na Internet também. Há inúmeros sites como [TurboSquid](https://www.turbosquid.com) que vendem modelos 3D, mas o problema é que nem todos os modelos que você comprar estarão preparados para serem utilizados em jogos (há diversas questões envolvidas, desde formato do arquivo até complexidade da malha, uso de mapas normais, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O módulo `pygame` do `Python` é baseado na `libsdl`. Conhecida como *Simple DirectMedia Layer* ou `SDL`.

A SDL não é uma biblioteca gráfica 3D. Conforme a informação contida na [página oficial](https://www.libsdl.org/):

> A SDL é uma biblioteca multimídia multiplataforma projetada para fornecer acesso de baixo nível ao áudio, teclado, mouse, joystick, e
>   ao hardware gráfico via OpenGL e Direct3D.

Esse "*Acesso ao hardware gráfico via OpenGL e Direct3D*" significa que a SDL contém algumas funções auxiliares para facilitar o uso multiplataforma do OpenGL, mas você ainda vai precisar implementar uma camada (*engine*) para OpenGL bruto, capaz de converter 2D para 3D e *vice-versa*.

Se você deseja uma abordagem mais específica para 3D, Talvez *engines* 3D, como o [`Ogre`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python-Ogre) ou [`Irrlicht`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyirrlicht), que usam o OpenGL (ou Direct3D no Windows) e fornecem API voltada para modelos gráficos em 3D.

Comment: O Pygame tem um módulo openGL também - mas é bem baixo nível e bem dificil de usar . então "é possível, mas não recomenddo". Os outros Engines, e também o Blender, com o Blender Game Engine são mais apropriados.

Comment: @jsbueno: Eu diria: Recomendado para propósitos didáticos e provas de conceito. (sem dizer que implementar um *engine* capaz de processar modelos gráficos 3D certamente é bem divertido!)